Provide custom CA to RabbitMQ.Client library
I am connecting to a RabbitMQ server with an internal hostname, using SSL. Here is my sample code:
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = "my_user";
factory.Password = "my_password";
factory.Port = 5671;

var endpoints = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AmqpTcpEndpoint> {
  new AmqpTcpEndpoint("mycluster.corp.internal",5671, new SslOption
  {
    Enabled = true
  })
};
using var conn = factory.CreateConnection(endpoints);
conn.CallbackException += (o, e) => {
    o.Dump();
    e.Dump();
};
using var model = conn.CreateModel();
model.CurrentQueue.Dump();
model.BasicPublish("my.exchange", "", body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"));

However the SSL certificate is generated by a custom CA (because it is an internal domain).
Is it possible to specify the custom CA in the client configuration?
